# ASP.NET Core web app, API controller not able to hit by Bearer token

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I have ASP.NET Core MVC web app where we have two controllers which load application UI and a Web API controller to access data from the UI.

Users accessing this web application through browsers are getting authenticated through OpenID Connnect which is working fine in the UI client and is able to access the Web API controller.

But I have external clients that also want to consume the Web API through bearer tokens.

They are always getting an error:

> Please sign in to access the endpoint

Can you please assist me how to achieve it?

- ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application (controller loading data through `HttpClient` calls to the Web API)
- ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Comment: Yes you are correct, Sorry for typo  update my query

Comment: What authority are you using now to get your token via OIDC? ADD meaning Azure Active Directory?

Comment: yes Azure Active Directory

Comment: Could you please share your configuration while getting the token and how you are sending token while user accessing API?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to implement it, if you need further help, please let me. Below sample works for me.

**Program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
//app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

**Controller.cs**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

**The API controller:**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[RequiredScope("Tiny.Read")]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**appsetting.json**

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "tenant_id",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id",
    "ClientId": "aad_client_id",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "Audience": "api://aad_client_id"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it works but I am not able to get OpenIdConnect and JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme events on code received, do you any idea about the same ?

Comment: can you please comment on my query

Comment: @AkhilTyagi [Try this.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F4XBjG)

Comment: I need event on builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));